# Showing menu make the cursor disappear

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The cursor disappears when making a single click, like so:

[image]

How to reproduce:

- get the Game Jam Menu template:
  https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/40465
- Add another scene with an FPS controller imported from the standard
  assets.
- Tick the "change scenes" in the UI -> start options component.
- Press escape and touch the slider, any single click will make the
  cursor disappear.

It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq1NR.jpg

If I tick off the mouse look -> lock cursor in the FPS controller then this doesn't happen, but I also see the cursor in my FPS game.

I tried to add `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked; Cursor.visible = false;` and the opposite when pausing and unpausing but it doesn't help. Probably because the `MouseLook.cs` is also updating them in:

[image]

I'd rather not couple the FPSController and the pause menu and they're also in different scenes.

So how else can I unlock the cursor when entering the pause menu? Is there an event pattern that can be used here?

It also darkens the scene, but that's for another question.

Comment: Please note that this is C# not unityscript and it's better to post the code instead of screenshot of it.

Comment: I must have misclicked the unityscript tag. I don't have a few lines of code that I can write here. It's a problem with standard assets and scenes made by the unity team... I upload this minimal project with those two scenes if someone will want.  @Programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been modified by the `MouseLook` script which is used in the `FirstPersonController` script. One solution is to modify the `MouseLook` script but a simple Asset update would kill that modification.

A proper solution to this problem is to disable the `FirstPersonController` script when you open up any menu and then enable it back when you close that menu. Also, when you disable it, manually set `Cursor.lockState` to `None` and set the cursor to visible.

Below is a simple function that will handle that. Each of your menu **open** and **close** button should be linked to the function below. *When you call it, pass `false` to it with the open button and `true` to it with the close button*:

```
void enableFPS(bool enable)
{
    GameObject fpsObj = GameObject.Find("FPSController");
    FirstPersonController fpsScript = fpsObj.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>();

    if (enable)
    {
        //Enable FPS script
        fpsScript.enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Disable FPS script
        fpsScript.enabled = false;
        //Unlock Mouse and make it visible
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but now they're strongly coupled, is this common in unity?

Comment: Yes. That's the annoying behavior of Unity's FPS. If you don't like it, write your own FPS code and use it. With your own FPS, you can make sure that it doesn't behave this way.